# How to read child component values from a parent method -- vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I have a dynamic list of custom components which are input fields.  From my parent vue ,when a button is clicked, how can I write a method that will loop through all the components in my list to get their values?

input-field.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input
      type="text"
      :name="name"
      :id="id"
      @input="valueChanged"
      v-model="val"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

app.vue

```
  <div>
    <ul>
      <ul v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
        <my-input :name="item.name" :id="item.id" @input="onChange" />
      </ul>
    </ul>
      <button>READ FIELDS</button>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import myInput from "./components/input-field.vue";
export default {
  name: "App",

  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        { id: "3", name: "test3" },
        { id: "4", name: "test4" },
        { id: "5", name: "test5" },
      ],
    };
  },
  components: {
    myInput
  },

  methods: {

//on button click function here
//how can I get the data from the my-input components
  }
};
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to *read* the values. Bind them like this: [Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

> *Read and understand what I have done, do not copy-paste. I have changed some of your code eg. imports*

#### input-field.vue

```html
<template>
  {{name}}
    <input type="text"
           :name="name"
           :id="id"
           :value="modelValue"
           @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)" />
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: ["modelValue", "id", "name"],
  emits: ["update:modelValue"]
}
</script>
```

#### app.vue

```html
<template>
  <div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
    <my-input :name="item.name" :id="item.id" v-model="item.value"></my-input>
  </div>
  <br />
  <b>Values in App.vue</b>
  <table border=1>
    <tr v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
      <td>{{item.id}}</td>
      <td>{{item.name}}</td>
      <td>{{item.value}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</template>
<script>
import myInput from "./input-field.vue";
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        { id: "3", name: "test3", value: "test input" },
        { id: "4", name: "test4", value: "" },
        { id: "5", name: "test5", value: "" },
      ],
    };
  },
  components: {
    myInput
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry if this is a basic question I am new to vue.   I see how you bound them to the table in the dom, but how can I access those values in javascript? I need to concatenate the values and then show them to the user.

Comment: Actually I have more use cases than just concatenate.  In general, I need to be able to use the values in javascript

Comment: You can. The values are available as `this.items`.

Comment: Oh, I understand now.  Thanks for the help